# gofabric8 deploy asking for for Username/Password

Tags: fabric8

I have been following the guide:
http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/aws.html

I am at the `gofabric8 deploy` step. When I run this command I am prompted for a Username and Password. Which Username/Password does this refer too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't need this if you've set the kubectl context as gofabric8 will reuse the details in ~/.kube/config

Do you get any results if you run `kubectl get nodes`?

If not could you try

`kubectl config set-credentials aws --username=kube --password=admin
kubectl config set-cluster aws --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --server=https://$YOUR_API_SERVER
kubectl config set-context aws --user=aws --namespace=default --cluster=aws
kubectl config use-context aws
kubectl get nodes`

And then when you get results back retry gofabric8 deploy.

Fingers crossed that works, if it does I'll update the docs.